# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial in android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

Hello there many question and answer availbe java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial i try all answer but not getting proper solutions for that, and this error occurred for very few device.

Like **HUAWEI Y6 Pro** Operating Systems **android Lollipop 5.0**

Here is my code call Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

startActivity(intent);
```

activity declared In manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Error Log as Below

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity } from ProcessRecord{3e3e2f8a 13479:com.lj.applocker/u0a114} (pid=13479, uid=10114) not exported from uid 1000
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2528)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3849)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3791)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
   at com.lj.applocker.common.BaseActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4130)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4098)
   at com.lj.applocker.common.BaseActivity.startActivity(Unknown Source)
   at com.lj.applocker.ui.activity.MainActivity.callSetting(Unknown Source)
   at com.lj.applocker.ui.activity.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(Unknown Source)
   at com.lj.applocker.ui.activity.MainActivity$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5667)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:962)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Any Help will appreciated

Thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem and how?

Comment: not yet, i jst write code in try and catch to prevent crash.

Answer (score 0):

Define permission in menifest like this,

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but already added in manifest see in updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a permission statement in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission  
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"  
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but already added in manifest, see in updated question